# Get all page/post IDs where a shortcode is used

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I want to know the page or post ID where this shortcode is apply in wordpress.

I have used this shortcode "[qsm quiz=6]" in wordpress page, now i want to show the page ID in another page where this shortcode is used.

Example: I have used shortcode in 2-3 pages, and i want these the pages IDs in a single page where this all shortcode is used.

Comment: If you're inside the shortcode's render function, you can use `get_the_ID()` to get the current page / post's ID.

Comment: I want to return Page ID in another page using some function.

Answer (score 4):

To Get the page/post id of the current page you can use `get_the_ID()` inside your shortcode function. This will give you the ID of the post/page wherever you apply the shortcode.

If you want the list of all the posts/pages using that particular shortcode you can use the following function.

```
function having_shortcode($str){
    $query = new WP_Query( "s='$str'" );
    $arr = array();
    if ($query->have_posts()){
      while ( $query->have_posts() ) { $query->the_post();
        $arr[] = get_the_ID().' '.get_the_title();
      } 
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

Just Simply Pass the shortcode name to the function and it will give you an array of the IDs of posts/pages that use shortcode.

In your case try doing this and you will get all the IDs

```
print_r(having_shortcode("[qsm quiz=6]"));
```

Comment: This will work when we get the output in same page, But i want this on different page, 

Example: I have used shortcode in 2-3 pages, and i want these the pages IDs in a single page where this all shortcode is used.

Comment: @RohitYaduvanshi See the Updated answer. let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

I try lots but in Last i found this best answer for that.

Used this code

```
global $wp, $wpdb;

$page_id = $wpdb->get_var('SELECT ID FROM '.$wpdb->prefix.'posts WHERE post_content LIKE "%[qsm quiz=6]%"');

echo $page_id;
```